# Iterating directories and conditions in makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a repository structure where dependencies can either be svn:external'd either in this repository or in a super-repository which has svn:external'd this one.  The externals are only one level deep and so if my repo is externalized by a super-repository, then I need to be able to detect where to find the dependency at a higher level, and copy over all relevant data.  If the dependency is indeed found in my own repository, then I need to build it.

I am having problems creating my makefile recipe to do this.  Here is what I have so far:

```
DEPENDENCIES = dep1 dep2
ROOTDIR = .

deps : 
    for dep in $(DEPENDENCIES); do \
        if [ -e $(ROOTDIR)/ext/$$dep ]; then \
            depdir = $(ROOTDIR)/ext/$$dep; \
            $(MAKE) -C $depdir; \
        elif [ -e $(ROOTDIR)/../$$dep ]; then \
            depdir = $(ROOTDIR)/../$$dep; \
        else \
            $(error Could not find dependency: $$dep) \
        fi \
        cp $$depdir/bin/* $(ROOTDIR)/bin; \
        cp $$depdir/lib/* $(ROOTDIR)/lib; \
        cp $$depdir/inc/$$dep $(ROOTDIR)/inc/$$dep; \
    done
```

First problem is the $(error ) line. I'd like to be able to throw an error, but this is clearly not subjected to the bash condition statements.  This is the output:

```
$ make deps
makefile:108: *** Could not find dependency: $dep.  Stop.
```

If I comment out that else statement, then I'm still having troubles

```
$ make deps
for dep in dep1 dep2; do \
        if [ -e ./ext/$dep ]; then \
/bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [makefile:106: deps] Error 1
```

Could someone provide some hints regarding how to accomplish this?  I'm running GNU make in both cygwin and linux environments.

**Edit**:  I'd really prefer to keep this as close to make as possible (and as little shell stuff).  I think I've gotten a little closer, but still need to repeat this for each item in $(DEPENDENCIES).

```
DEPENDENCIES = foo bar
ROOTDIR = .
EXTDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/ext
BINDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/bin
INCDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/inc

# Need a foreach DEP in $(DEPENDENCIES) here
ifneq("$(wildcard $(EXTDIR)/$(DEP))","")  
DEPDIR = $(EXTDIR)/$(DEP)
BUILDDEP = $(MAKE) -C $(DEPDIR)/build
else ifneq("$(wildcard $(ROOTDIR)../$(dep))", "") 
DEPDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/../$(dep)
else
$(error Could not find dependency: $(DEP))
endif 

$(DEPDIR) :
    $(BUILDDEP)
    cp $(DEPDIR)/bin/* $(BINDIR)
    cp $(DEPDIR)/inc/$(DEP)/* $(INCDIR)/$(DEP)
```

**Edit2:** 
I think I'm getting closer.  The following looks more like what I want, but it still have problems: 
1) I don't know how to call each recipe
2) It doesn't give an error if it doesn't find all dependencies
3) It doesn't let me dictate the build order
4) It doesn't let me filter to use only folders listed in dependencies (it does all folders)

```
ifneq "$(wildcard $(EXTDIR)/%/build)" ""  
$(EXTDIR)/%:
    $(MAKE) -C $(EXTDIR)/%/build
    cp $(EXTDIR)/%/bin/* $(BINDIR)
    cp $(EXTDIR)/%/int/*.a $(INTDIR)
    cp $(EXTDIR)/%/inc/%/* $(INCDIR)/%
endif

ifneq "$(wildcard $(ROOTDIR)/../%/build)" ""
DEPDIR = $(ROOTDIR)/..
$(DEPDIR)/%: 
    cp $(DEPDIR)/%/bin/* $(BINDIR)
    cp $(DEPDIR)/%/int/*.a $(INTDIR)
    cp $(DEPDIR)/%/inc/%/* $(INCDIR)/%
endif
```

**Edit3**
After being told I was trying to solve too many problems at once,  I've reduced it to this:

```
DEPENDENCIES = dep1 dep2 dep3

for each DEP in $(DEPENDENCIES)

$(DEP) : 
    $(MAKE) -C ../ext/$(DEP)
```

How can I create a recipe ($(DEP) ) for each item in $(DEPENDENCIES)?

Comment: You're writing a shell script, not a Makefile: there are no rules in there.  Turn it into a shell script!

Comment: You're trying to solve too many problems at once. Try to do this from the command line (i.e. without Make), and if you have trouble with part of it, reduce that problem to its core (e.g. how do I throw an error in bash?), and if you can't solve that problem, ask about it here.

Comment: It's easy for me to do this from the command line.  However, I'd prefer to use make so that: 
A) This framework can be generalized and easily configured for use by other developers
B) I am not stuck with g++ and Linux.  We'd also like to develop in Windows with MinGW and so Bash is not a good language for me to use.

Comment: Your solution is also parallel safe. Give `-j5` (say) to _make_ and _make_ will ensure your CPUs are kept busy across all the sub-makes. Nice. One note: You probably want to add `.PHONY: ${DEPENDENCIES}` to mark them as symbolic targets, otherwise it will misbehave if someone creates a file called `../ext/dep2` (say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  This solves the problem above:

```
DEPENDENCIES = dep1 dep2 dep3
$(DEPENDENCIES) : 
    $(MAKE) -C ../ext/$@
```

The answer is very simple.  I wish I knew enough about this stuff to ask a more legible question.